What do these lines represent on the USGS topographic base map WMS represent?
The USGS National Map's topographic base map WMS show the blue lines (see below) extending across marine waters when zoomed in to a scale of 1:50500.  I am trying to determine what these lines represent.
I can see from the downloadable USGS topographic map legend that some of the blue lines close to island groups represent the (alleged) areas exposed during low tides.  Having some expert knowledge of the area I know that the lines in question shown below are not areas exposed during low tides.  Furthermore, I am well aware that these lines are not ferry routes, administrative borders, or undersea cables.
In addition to adding the WMS to my map layouts I can view the USGS topomap as an ESRI online map but in this case no legend is provide.

What are the blue lines highlighted with question marks supose to represent?  The lines (if they were un-surveyed shorelines as suggested in the comments would cross in international commercial shipping lane as shown here in the NOAA nautical chart for the area:


Shoreline (cartographic) if dotted is un-surveyed. https://pubs.usgs.gov/gip/TopographicMapSymbols/topomapsymbols.pdf

1 Variant - baselines from which the breadth of the territorial sea is measured...
2 Variant - boundaries of gulfs, straits, bays, etc. transferred from nautical charts....
